# I am trying to implement Pocketsphinx running uClinux, but I keep getting "Phone is missing in acoustic model" errors

Tags: voice-recognition, cmusphinx, uclinux, blackfin

I am trying to run *Pocketsphinx* on a microcontroller running *uClinux*, I have installed pocketsphinx on the controller, but I keep getting several different errors regarding acoustic models and definitions. The current one I am facing is:

> "Phone ... is missing in the acoustic model"
>
> Replace the ... with every possible phonetic combination. It starts
>   off with A, then AE, then progresses to B etc.

I am trying to take a *.wav* file as input, and so this is the command I am using to run the software:

```
pocketsphinx_continuous -hmm /usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en/tidigits/ -lm /usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/lm/en/tidigits.DMP -infile 1.wav -samprate 8000 -dict cmu07a.dic
```

Has anyone encountered this issue? if so, do you know a way to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For tidigits model there is a special dictionary `tidigits.dic` in `pocketsphinx/model/lm/en/tidigits.dic`, you need to use with `-dict` option instead of `cmu07a.dic`in your command line.